# Dynamic object property lookup via object and key in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a generic function that takes an object and a key and then manipulates the value at the key. The function needs to take any number or arbitrary objects and any arbitrary key name. In JavaScript the function is:

```js
function setVal(obj, key) {
  obj[key] = 2;
}
```

However, i am really struggling to write this function in TypeScript. I understand that TS wants to know the type of the object in order to operate on it. I have tried to set the type conditionally but it errors:

```js
interface Bar {
  bar: number;
}

interface Qux {
  qux: number;
}

const bar: Bar = {
  bar: 1
}

const qux: Qux = {
  qux: 1
}

type Key = 'bar' | 'qux';

type Obj<T extends Key> = T extends 'bar'
  ? Bar
  : Qux;

function setVal<T extends Key>(obj: Obj<T>, key: T) {
  obj[key] = 2; // ERROR: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'Obj<T>'
}

setVal(bar, 'bar');
```

If anyone can explain how to get this function to work in TS i would be really grateful.